What text (control characters) have special meaning in an LLM prompt?
Example:   
BACKGROUND:
I had a prompt failing on gpt4o. I narrowed it down to  < >.
I was passing in text with < tags>:
The official languages of Switzerland are German, Italian, Romansch, and French.
After a bit of research, I found folks talking about including instructions with in angle brackets .  So it seems the LLMs treat < > different than regular text.  It occured to me there might be other "control characters".


What text (control characters) have special meaning in an LLM prompt?

AFAIK, none. < and > are treated like normal chars with GPT 4o 2024-08-06:

